# How do I remove functions installed using source()

Tags: r

I recently installed Rand Wilcox's functions for robust techniques using:

```
source ("http://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/239/docs/Rallfun-v27.txt")
```

Unfortunately I'm finding that when I try to use other packages I now get a lot of masking errors of the type:

```
The following objects are masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    ancboot, ancova, bwtrim, lincon, mcp2a, mcp2atm, mcppb20, med1way, med2way, mest,
    msmedse, pairdepb, pb2gen, pbad2way, rmanova, rmanovab, rmmcp, rungen, runmbo,
    runmean, sppba, sppbb, sppbi, t1way, t1waybt, t2way, t3way, trimse, tsplit, winmean,
    winse, yuen, yuenbt, yuend
```

I'd like to uninstall/remove the functions from R but I'm not having much luck. Does anyone know how to remove things installed using the source() function?

Cheers

Comment: Can you not afford to restart `R`?

Answer (score 2):

Functions created using `source` are just objects like anything else and are usually in your global environment (as they are here). In that case they should be removable just using `rm` (see `?rm`).

Are they there when you type `ls()`? .... then you can just use `rm` to remove them.

But you can use the functions that are masked in any case, if you specify where they're from. `mypackage:::myfunction` should usually do it, or if the package is loaded two colons should suffice